# svnadmin dump - svn: Revision file lacks trailing newline

Tags: svn, commit, dump

I'm trying to migrate one SVN repo to another server.
When I try svnadmin dump It fails with:

```
svnadmin: E160004: Revision file (r66000) lacks trailing newline
```

The problem is that the dump fails on revision 66000 out of 110000, and I can't apply the following [fix](http://www.jamesstroud.com/jamess-miscellaneous-how-tos/os-x-admin/fix-svn-revision-file-lacks-trailing-newline).

If you have any ideas how to migrate the repo to the new server I'll be very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a working solution for me.
Using "svndumpfilter include" I've dumped all the required folders from the old repo and load them to the new one successfully.
Now the new repository has no broken revisions and can be dumped in
order to backup.
By this way you are loosing some files which have broken revisions, but I didn't needed them anyway.

The other way is to tar the repo and extract it to the new SVN server.